# PHP getting copy function to work

Tags: php, copy

My copy code doesnt work for some reason. Tried several things.

this is the code that I am trying to use

```
$fb_foto_url = $userData['picture']['data']['url']; 
$plaats = '/assets/images/profielfotos/fiel.jpg';
copy($fb_foto_url, $plaats);
```

The `$userData['picture']['data']['url']`is getting filled with this for example: https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=113831052838678&height=200&width=200&ext=1527931138&hash=AeSlklMNX6l4Uanh

I need that to get stored in on the server. But it isn't working for some reason. I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what.
If someone can help me with this code, would be nice.

Comment: Paths, paths to files.

Comment: @u_mulder what do you mean?

Comment: Sure that `/assets/images/profielfotos/` exists? Know the difference between absolute and relative paths?

Comment: Please stop asking that same question over and over with a new account each time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600264/ is the last one I can find, but I am pretty sure you asked this multiple times over the last days already, each time with a fresh account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file_put_contents($plaats,file_get_contents($fb_foto_url));
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPs `copy` function expects path's, not URL's.

A (server-) path is a directory name on the machine the PHP code is executed on.

An URL is a virtual name that may or may not point to such a physical path or is resolved dynamically.

Example:

The server path to a websites images might be `/var/www/example.org/assets/images/`, while the URL is `http://example.org/assets/images/`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Quote manual: _“Both source and dest may now be URLs if the "fopen wrappers" have been enabled.”_ - “now” referring back to PHP 4.3.0 already.

Comment: @CBroe `fopen wrappers` is disabled on most simple web-hosting environments I know…

Comment: Be that as it may, but I think you’ll agree that that’s something else than saying “PHPs copy function expects path's, not URL's” across-the-board. (Although I am not to sure that using a URL for _dest_ would actually make sense, since the description of the HTTP wrapper explicitly says it doesn’t support writing. Maybe that applies in terms of when the URL actually maps to the local file system only.)